# How do you reconcile these two verses: [ואחרי ככלות הכל לבדו ימלוך נורא] -- [אף תכון תבל בל תמוט]

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, shacharis-morning-prayer

If it would have been written like this:

...ואפילו אם ככלות הכל

then it would have made more sense. But the way it's written like this:

...ואחרי ככלות הכל

Makes it sound like it is indeed going to happen.

Comment: (1) What does the "אף תכון תבל בל תמוט" line (in the title) have to do with your question? It doesn't appear in the "[אדון עולם](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adon_Olam#Text)" poem (which I assume is where you got the "ואחרי ככלות הכל לבדו ימלוך נורא" line from). (2) You could improve the question with why _you_ think "ואחרי ככלות הכל" is problematic, and should have been composed differently. (I am not suggesting here that it either is or isn't problematic, but only how you could improve your question.)

Comment: @TamirEvan my question was how do you reconcile these two different verses. I didn't imply they were in the same section

Comment: Mentioning text ("ואחרי ככלות הכל לבדו ימלוך נורא // אף תכון תבל בל תמוט") in the title of a question, and only quoting part of it ("ואחרי ככלות הכל") in the body of the question, would imply (to me) that the _whole_ text was from one source, quoted in full in the title for context, but only "ואחרי ככלות הכל" was relevant to the question itself. As I only know of "ואחרי ככלות הכל לבדו ימלוך נורא" in "אדון עולם", and as it doesn't have "אף תכון תבל בל תמוט", I asked that question. Also, the "//" looks like a [caesura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesura), a metrical pause or break in a verse.

Comment: @TamirEvan I edited it. let me know what you think or if you have a better recommendation. (though, most people are very familiar with ....ואחרי ככלות so i don't think anyone will have any doubts.)

Answer (score 1):

The term תבל refers to the terrestial world, like it says ([Tehillim 24:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.24.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

> לְדָוִ֗ד מִ֫זְמ֥וֹר לַֽ֭יהוָה הָאָ֣רֶץ וּמְלוֹאָ֑הּ **תֵּ֝בֵ֗ל**
> וְיֹ֣שְׁבֵי בָֽהּ׃  Of David. A psalm. The earth is the LORD’s and all
> that it holds, the world and its inhabitants.

The fact that the terrestial world is in existence, floating in outer space and yet functioning is a major miracle, as the verse states ([Iyov 26:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Job.26.7?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en)):

> נֹטֶ֣ה צָפ֣וֹן עַל־תֹּ֑הוּ תֹּ֥לֶה אֶ֝֗רֶץ עַל־בְּלִי־מָֽה׃  He it is
> who stretched out Zaphon over chaos, Who suspended earth over
> emptiness.

This is is part of Hashem's promise that the physical earth will continue to exist since mankind needs the world in order to fulfill their mission here. As long as the physical universe is needed, the world will always remain and will never be destroyed.

However, the physical world is not eternal. There was a time before the world was created, and there will be a time after the physical world no longer be needed. The physical world by definition is finite which means it is not eternal. (See Mishneh Torah, [Yesodei HaTorah 1:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foundations_of_the_Torah.1.7?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he))
Yet Hashem is eternal. He existed before the world was created and He will continue to exist forever. This is what it meant by that phrase from [Adon Olam](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Preparatory_Prayers%2C_Adon_Olam.1-2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he),

> אֲדוֹן עוֹלָם אֲשֶׁר מָלַךְ, בְּטֶֽרֶם כָּל יְצִיר נִבְרָא... וְאַחֲרֵי
> כִּכְלוֹת הַכֹּל, לְבַדּוֹ יִמְלֹךְ נוֹרָא
> The Master of the World that ruled before anything was created... And after everything is complete/finished, the Awesome One will rule alone...
> :

Comment: so you are implying that the world will no longer exist at a certain time?  Do You have any sources for that? And when do you think it's going to happen, after Moshiach comesthe world will cease to exist?

Comment: @larry909 I added in a link to Rambam who says that every physical body must have an end. That's how we know Hashem isn't physical; if he was physical, he would have an end after which he will cease to exist (which can't be as he said earlier.) That's a definite source IMO for what I wrote. I also remember seeing sources discussing the 8th millennium- after 6000yrs of creation, 1000ys of Moshiach, what comes next? Not necessarily the same physical world we have. I can't find right now who discusses it, but when I do I'll add that in as well.